# Java connect to OracleDB : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO error: The pipe has been cut

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I'm try to using java to connect to Oracle DB (11g) using flowing source:

```
try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP_ADDRESS:1521/SERVCE_NAME", "USER", "PASS");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

It's work well on my old database, but it's fail on new database

It's can not get the connection, the error is:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO error: The pipe has been cut.
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:752)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
>               at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>               at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>               at main.main(main.java:30)
>       Caused by: java.net.SocketException: pipe has been cut.
>               at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>               at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
>               at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
>               at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:209)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:215)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:302)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:429)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receive(T4C8TTIdty.java:706)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:613)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4
>
> CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1607)
>                   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4
>
> CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
>               ... 6 more

What is: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO error: The pipe has been cut mean ?
Please help me to slove this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> What is: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO error: The pipe has been cut mean ?

The answer to this question is given in the JavaDoc as:

> The subclass of SQLException thrown in situations where a previously failed operation might be able to succeed if the application performs some recovery steps and retries the entire transaction or in the case of a distributed transaction, the transaction branch. At a minimum, the recovery operation must include closing the current connection and getting a new connection. ([Source JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html) )

The main problem might be that you are using a wrong name for the Oracle JDBC driver. The correct driver name is called:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

So replace `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` with this one.

And the connection url should be as follows:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP_ADDRESS:1521/SERVCE_NAME
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) you will find more detailed information how to use JDBC drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried, but it's same error occur.

Comment: From what I see there shouldn't be any problem if you have corrected the driver and the connection url. You may use the debugger to find out at what point you are getting this exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't direct access to DB from local machine (eclipse); I have to create jar file to test the connection. Maybe the error come from remote server or database server; but I don't know where is the root cause.

Comment: In that case, the error may lie in the connection to the server and may not be in the code. Either you use a tool like DbVisualizer to test your connection or you install Oracle XE  on your local machine and test your code against it so that you can verify that the error is not  in your code.